# How do I make a counter go up to a certain value then reset to 0?

Tags: python

I need to make an internal counter that goes to the set period then resets to 0. Now because the class is called upon every time and **`__init__`** it makes ***self.time*** always be equal to 0 and I'll never get the color to *'R'*. I'm not allowed to import anything or add another function.

I've tried various methods but nothing that shows any positive results. I still only get either everything is *'G'* or invalid syntax.

```
class Light:
    def __init__(self, period, green_period):
        self.time = 0
        self.period = period
        self.color = 'G'
        if self.time > green_period:
            self.color = 'R'
        if self.time > self.period:
            self.time = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return f'({self.color})'

    def step(self):
        self.time += 1

    def is_green(self):
        if self.color == 'G':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

To try this code out I'm going with:

```
def demo_light():
    a_light = Light(7, 3)
        for i in range(15):
            print(i, a_light,
                a_light.is_green())
            a_light.step()

demo_light()
```

This is the output I'm expecting:

```
0 (G) True
1 (G) True
2 (G) True
3 (R) False
4 (R) False
5 (R) False
6 (R) False
7 (G) True
8 (G) True
9 (G) True
10 (R) False
11 (R) False
12 (R) False
13 (R) False
14 (G) True
```

And this is what I get:

```
0 (G) True
1 (G) True
2 (G) True
3 (G) True
4 (G) True
5 (G) True
6 (G) True
7 (G) True
8 (G) True
9 (G) True
10 (G) True
11 (G) True
12 (G) True
13 (G) True
14 (G) True
```

Comment: The checks in `__init__` should be moved to `step` or better to a new method which is then called from `__init__` and `step`-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is asking but I think the following may help. I move the code that checks the time and changes to the colour to the step method as the **init** method is only called when the object is created, therefore the colours are not then checked again.

```
class Light:
def __init__(self, period, green_period):
    self.time = 0
    self.period = period
    self.green_period =green_period 
    self.step()

def __str__(self):
    return f'({self.color})'

def step(self):
    self.time += 1
    self.color = 'G'
    if self.time > self.green_period:
        self.color = 'R'
    if self.time > self.period:
        self.time = 0



def is_green(self):
    if self.color == 'G':
        return True
    else:
        return False


def demo_light():
    a_light = Light(7, 3)
    for i in range(15):
        print(i, a_light,
            a_light.is_green())
        a_light.step()

demo_light()
```

Produces the output:

```
0 (G) True
1 (G) True
2 (G) True
3 (R) False
4 (R) False
5 (R) False
6 (R) False
7 (R) False
8 (G) True
9 (G) True
10 (G) True
11 (R) False
12 (R) False
13 (R) False
14 (R) False
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this problem for about a week and never realized that the solution was pretty easy in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your color state is  a function of `time` and `green_period`. You can write `is_green` like this:

```
def is_green(self):
    return self.time % self.period < self.green_period
```

Just make sure you store the `green_period` in `self.green_period`.

However, since `color` is a function you can make it a function. So the complete class would be:

```
class Light:
    def __init__(self, period, green_period):
        self.time = 0
        self.period = period
        self.green_period = green_period

    def __str__(self):
        return f'({self.color})'

    def color(self):
        return 'G' if self.time % self.period < self.green_period else 'R'

    def step(self):
        self.time += 1

    def is_green(self):
        return self.color() == 'G'
```

It would also be nice to *rotate* time (instead of only incrementing it) if its not needed elsewhere.

The problem you currently have is that you never re-evaluate the color.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution, the only thing is that I'm not allowed to add the extra function "color". But in any other case, I'd totally use this.

Answer (score 0):

Two quick notes. You need to add setting the colour to `'R'` and the reset to `'G'` with resetting the counter in step. Also you should initialise `self.time` as `1` if you want it to behave as your saying. See full code below:

```
class Light:
  def __init__(self, period, green_period):
    self.time = 1 # Initialised as 1 instead
    self.period = period
    self.color = 'G'
    self.green_period = green_period # Added so class can retrieve it
    # Removed steps here

  def __str__(self):
    return f'({self.color})'

  def step(self):
    self.time += 1
    if self.time > self.green_period:
      self.color = 'R'
    if self.time > self.period: # Added check and reset here
      self.color = 'G'
      self.time = 1 # Initialised as 1 instead

  def is_green(self):
    if self.color == 'G':
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your conditions in the **init** were badly placed.

Please find below my trial, it produces your expected result :

```py
class Light:
    def __init__(self, period, green_period): # 7, 3
        self.time = 1
        self.period = period # 7
        self.color = 'G'
        self.green_period = green_period

    def __str__(self):
        return f'({self.color})'

    def step(self):
        self.time += 1
        if self.time > self.green_period:
            self.color = 'R'
        if self.time > self.period:
            self.__init__(self.period, self.green_period)

    def is_green(self):
        if self.color == 'G':
            return True
        else:
            return False

def demo_light():
    a_light = Light(7, 3)
    for i in range(15):
        print(i, a_light, a_light.is_green())
        a_light.step()

demo_light()
```

```
0 (G) True
1 (G) True
2 (G) True
3 (R) False
4 (R) False
5 (R) False
6 (R) False
7 (G) True
8 (G) True
9 (G) True
10 (R) False
11 (R) False
12 (R) False
13 (R) False
14 (G) True
```